# Devise - change error message without hardcoded in yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I authenticate user by Devise with keys `config.authentication_keys = [ :email , :company_id ]`

In `config/locales/devise.en.yml`, the fail message is configured:

```
    invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
```

So, wrong authentication with message (what I don't like):

```
    Invalid email, company_id or password.
```

How can I change the message like this

```
    Invalid email, company or password.
```

without hardcoded `invalid: "Invalid email, company or password."` in `devise.en.yml`:

Comment: please help me. Sorry all, my question is not clear?

Comment: You can use this.

    invalid: "Invalid email, company or password."

Comment: I dont want to hardcoded (I mentioned it in my questions). It is better if there is `config.authentication_key_labels` in the `devise.yml`, sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email , :company_id ]
config.authentication_key_labels = config.authentication_keys.join(', ').gsub('_id','')

invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_key_labels} or password."
```

---

Edit: since devise itself doesn't have a place to store them, I can't find a way to do what you require. Editing strings in the yaml file itself is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstand my words. I assume that Devise has an attribute `authentication_key_labels ` for custom label. But, it is not defined in model Devise. Please see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/18b6064d74726147eccd69b24812000074261bbb/test/rails_app/config/initializers/devise.rb